# Subclipse error message "Expected format '3' of repository; found format '5'"

Tags: eclipse, svn

I installed subclipse in eclipse, but I get an error message "Expected format '3' of repository; found format '5'" when I try to open a repository.

Here is the sequence of steps that leads to the error message.

Select "Window -> Open Perspective -> SNV Repository Exploring" from the Eclipse main menu.

Right click on the "SVN Repository" tab.  Select "New -> Repository Location..." from the pop-up menu. The "Add SVN Repository" panel appears.

Enter "file:///Users/caylespandon/svn/MyProject" in the "Url" field. Click on the "Finish" buton.

A panel with the following error message appears:

```
Unable to Validate
Error validating location: "org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException:
Couldn't open a repository
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///Users/caylespandon/svn/MyProject'
Unsupported repository version
svn: Expected format '3' of repository; found format '5'
"
```

Note that I can access the same repository from the command line just fine:

```
~> svn checkout file:///Users/caylespandon/svn/MyProject
A   MyProject/trunk
A   MyProject/trunk/Jamrules
A   MyProject/trunk/.project
A   MyProject/trunk/setenv
[...]
```

Here is the version information:

Eclipse: version 3.4.0 build id I20080617-2000

Subclipse version: 1.2.0

SVN version: 1.4.4 (r25188)

Running on a Mac: OS X version 10.5.4

PS -- If your answer involves switching from file to svn+ssh, please explain why and how to convert an existing repository from file to svn+ssh without losing any history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help on your posted problem, but I would recommend trying subversive instead.  I made the switch out of frustration with some subclipse bugs and have been much happier.  It does take a bit more work to install.

[Eclipse Subversive Project](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing here, but make sure your version of the libsvnjavahl libraries are the same as the version of SVN you're using.

Comment: the problem is that the macosx development tools bring their own subversion version with it, quite old (1.2 or 1.3, something like it.) Either you upgrade to a newer subversion on your mac, or you use the older libraries for your eclipse (I suggest the first option). The java libs are included with the subclipse plugin, but you can donwload them separately from the subclipse website.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122533/how-can-i-downgrade-the-format-of-a-subversion-repositiory) to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering myself)

I ended up picking the solution suggested by Cory Engebretson, which is to use Subversive instead of Subclipse. I did some googling to see if one is better than the other, and they seem to be pretty much equivalent some like one and some the other. I found the help (particualarly the installation instructions) for Subversive clearer and I was able to get it to work without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you are using an old SVN client that does not understand the newer format (5) of the SVN repository.