# How to downgrade a subversion tree from v1.7 to v1.6?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to downgrade a subversion working copy from version 1.7 to version 1.6x?

Version 1.7 uses a single .svn root folder and sqlite for metadata so the conversion python script from tigris.org does not work.

Do you know of a solution that does not involve making a clean checkout under v1.6 and copying over the modified files?

Comment: Is 1.7 yet released? Which client is supporting it?

Comment: For windows beta versions are available from the TortoiseSVN nightly builds site at http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/

Answer (score 18):

There is a [script](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/change-svn-wc-format.py) to do working copy downgrades.

However, this does not support downgrading from the 1.7 format to the 1.6 format, nor will it ever support this in the future. The comments in the script tell us why this is impossible:

```
  # Downgrading from format 11 (1.7-dev) to format 10 is not possible,
  # because 11 does not use has-props and cachable-props (but 10 does).
  # Naively downgrading in that situation causes properties to disappear
  # from the wc.
```

Comment: @fishbone: I assume you mean that one of the other answers should be voted above this one. Note that those answers will not actually preserve the state of your working copy. To give one example, if you had done a "svn mv foo bar" then after the downgrade you'd see that foo is "missing" and bar is "unversioned". Uncommitted SVN property modifications would be lost entirely. So IMO "it can't be done" is still a valid answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault, I have to remove the downvote. It sounded to me like "How can I downgrade 1.7 to 1.6" - "I know a script which exactly can't do that" :D . I misunderstood the script's comments, which are the actual point of your answer. Edit: I can't remove the vote until this answer is edited :(

Comment: @WimCoenen, you better wrap it up above, and conclude with "it can't be made".
For me, I will solve this by backup before upgrading to do a downgrade afterwards ...

Answer (score 14):

I found the best way to delete the .svn folder from the 1.7 working copy then checkout the 1.6 on top of it. It worked for me, it might work for you as well. (with using tortoiseSvn 1.6.x client)

Comment: This worked pretty well for me. I was able to keep the changes I had made locally. Some extra files turned up modified but I was able to revert them.

Comment: My reason for needing to downgrade is so I can copy a 30gb checkout from a workstation with 1.7 to a workstation with 1.6 (from Ubuntu 12.10 to 12.04). I haven't tried this, but this sounds like a very plausible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

My dirty solution was to create a clean checkout using v1.6 and then copy only the `.svn` folders to the existing working copy using a little bash script:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  target=/projects/working-copy-dir

  svn_dirs=`find . -type d -iname .svn`

  for svn_dir in $svn_dirs; do
      tosvn_dir=$target${svn_dir/\.\//}  # strip the extra './' path component
      cp -r $svn_dir $tosvn_dir
  done
```

This assumes the script is run from the clean checkout dir. `Target` is the modified working copy. The top-level v1.7 `.svn` dir should be removed/renamed before running the script.

ps. I am not going to mark this as an answer for the time being, because the solution above is a workaround and does not actually convert the project from 1.7 to 1.6. So the question remains open.

Answer (score 2):

(assuming the files on server are correct)
Best way i found so far:

1. close your IDE
2. delete local files
3. remove svn 1.7
4. install svn 1.6
5. checkout files

Comment: I would do this also but the question was about how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses synaptic package manager, so ensure it is installed.

1. Append the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
   ```

   This will ensure you have at least two versions to select from, i.e 1.7 and 1.6.
2. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Go to the package manager, search for `subversion` and select it.
4. From the menu *select package* -> *force-version* select *1.6* or *right click*  -> *properties* -> version select *1.6*.
5. Install the package
6. Select package again, then *menu* -> *lock version*.

   This is to prevent automatic updates to higher versions.

This is it. Good luck.